# Using Handlebars in the Browser as an ES6 Module

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, es6-modules

I am trying to use Handlebars in the Browser (client-side script). I am importing a js module templating.js (see below) and want to import the Handlebars library as an ES6 module but can't find any documentation.

In the example below I was lifting the contents of the following js library as handlebars.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.6/handlebars.js

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Templating</title>
  <meta name="description" content="example showing how to template content">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templating.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.6/handlebars.min.js" integrity="sha512-zT3zHcFYbQwjHdKjCu6OMmETx8fJA9S7E6W7kBeFxultf75OPTYUJigEKX58qgyQMi1m1EgenfjMXlRZG8BXaw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="module" src="templating.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  <h1>Templating</h1>
  </header>
  <main>

  </main>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

```js
/* templating.js */

import { Handlebars } from './handlebars.js' // v4.7.6

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded')
})
```

I'm getting the error: requested module './handlebars.js' does not provide an export named 'Handlebars'

Does anyone know:

1. What handlebars library to use?
2. How to import this into my script?

Any help greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading handlebars via a script tag will expose it as a UMD (universal module definition).  This just means that all functionality of the library is exposed via global variable(s).  In the case of the library link you provided, the main global variable appears to be `Handlebars`.

If you would like to import handlebars directly into your script as a CommonJS/ES6 module, you would need to use a build tool such as Webpack.

Try rendering your HTML document in a browser and then typing `Handlebars` in the devtools console, you should see an object containing all of Handlebars' exported functions.